# How does the 555 timer IC circuit work?

Tags: capacitor, timer, 555

As a beginner to electronics I'm having a tough time understanding circuits that have a combination of different components, including the following timer circuit. Its based around a LM555 timer IC. I get the potentiometer and the resistors, but a couple of other things go over my head.

1) why's there a connection from between R1 and R2 to pin 7? Is it working as a voltage divider?

2)Whats the purpose of the capacitors C1 and C2?

[image]

Comment: This can't be explained without you first understanding what a 555 timers does.  For starters, read the datasheet and put descriptive names on all the pins in your schematic.  If that doesn't then explain the circuit to you already, at least we will know what you have connectd to what pins.  You can't really expect people to remember the pinout of a IC they last used 30 years ago.

Comment: That's an awful schematic, which requires the engineer to remember which pins of the IC do what. It's better to have pin names and numbers. (E.g. pin names inside the box, pin numbers outside).

Comment: In his book " Make: Electronics" author Charles Platt has set out in a clear and easy to understand explanation of how the 555 operates (pages 153 to about 180). If you can get a good used copy (try Amazon.com for a used copy, or other suppliers) it has tons of useful information for the newbie electronics enthusiast.

Answer (score 2):

In astable mode, the 555 timer puts out a continuous stream of rectangular pulses having a specified frequency. Resistor R1 is connected between VCC and the discharge pin (pin 7) and another resistor (R2) is connected between the discharge pin (pin 7), and the trigger (pin 2) and threshold (pin 6) pins that share a common node. Hence the capacitor is charged through R1 and R2, and discharged only through R2, since pin 7 has low impedance to ground during output low intervals of the cycle, therefore discharging the capacitor. Also that
the circuit configuration above does not permit a duty cycle of less than 50%, because the time-constant for charging C1 is always greater than for discharging. To achieve any arbitrary duty cycle, R2 can be moved to be in series with pin 7, the discharge pin. The duration of the high-output interval (during the charging of C1) is then 0.693(R1C1), and the low-output interval (while discharging C1) is 0.693(R2C1). The total time period, T, is 0.693(R1+R2)C1

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i suggest you is to use more the documentation about the IC in the center, because the rest of the schematic is for making the ic working.
And a lot of information are in the technical documentation

> 1) why's there a connection from between R1 and R2 to pin 7? Is it
>   working as a voltage divider?

The connection between those two resistor is an voltage divider.

> 2)Whats the purpose of the capacitors C1 and C2?

C1 is the capacitor that will make the 555 ic make it's clock.

From the technical documentation: C2 is the capacitor used to remove the noise in astable mode:

Pin 5. – Control Voltage, This pin controls the timing of the 555 by overriding the 2/3Vcc level of the voltage divider network. By applying a voltage to this pin the width of the output signal can be varied independently of the RC timing network. When not used it is connected to ground via a 10nF capacitor to eliminate any noise.

A great tutorial for you on the 555 oscillator mode (astable), (timer is monostable)
Astable mode from www.electronics-tutorials.ws:

[image]
[image]

The capacitor showing here is C1

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html

It explain all this circuit and all the formula to make your own circuit that suit your need

A great video from GreatScoot can help you understand the usage of the circuit and the component that are in the schematic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLaexx-NMj8

Answer (score 0):

"Schematic of the LED flasher circuit" by this explanation this 555 chip is working like a PWM (pulse width modulation) modulator most likely. Potentiometer in the schema controls the pulse width i think.

Now that you've got a lead, you can download a 555 datasheet and read application notes in it.

When you encounter a component you don't know, it is best to read its datasheet for basic information at first.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Internal block diagram of a 555]

As you can see here from the block diagram from wikipedia, Pin 7 provides a direct connection to ground or causes pin 7 to be an open circuit depending upon the state of the RS-latch. This means that you either have both R1 and R2 as a current path to charge capacitor C1 on the charge cycle while pin 7 is open or you have R2 connected to ground on the discharge cycle. When the capacitor is charged to a certain level, it causes pins 6 to trip causing the RS latch to change state. This forces Pin 7 to short to ground. The capacitor will discharge through R2 and Pin 7 until Pin 2 threshold is tripped. Then it cycles back and forth between these two charge/discharge states endlessly.

This results in a output high time of the time it takes to charge the cap up to pin 6 threshold level, and an output low time of the time it takes to discharge the cap to pin 2. The calculated times may be seen here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Astable

Lastly, you ask what Cap2 does. As you can see from the diagram, it's connected to pin 5 which is the trigger set-point side of the comparators. This capacitor is acting as a bypass capacitor which helps to stabilize the voltage set points. If this is 555 is switching, it's possible that it's drawing significant current during the discharge phase. In that case, the VCC would droop. The capacitor at pin 5 helps prevent the trigger voltage from drooping as well. In that way, you have a more stable and consistent frequency that the output would switch at.